# problem with reading a file or classes giving each student a quiz

Tags: java, arrays, string, file, class

Hi there i have a problem in the main method
the problem is that i can't read quizz to each student correctly 
somehow it takes the last quiz for all students 
[how my output is different than my input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dwqmx.png)
i don't know if the problem is caused by FileInputStream or the classes or even the constructor..

also i mustn't use BufferedReader ....

My code :

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class Student {
    // private variables
    private int studentID;
    private String name;
    private double[] grade = new double[4];

    public Student(String name, int id, double[] grade) {
        // here is our constructor
        this.grade = grade;
        this.name = name;
        this.studentID = id;
    }

    public int getStudentID() {
        return this.studentID;
    }

    public double[] getGrades() {
        return this.grade;

    }

    public String toString() {
        // overriding toString
        return this.studentID + "\t" + this.name + "\t" + this.grade[0] + " " + this.grade[1] + " " + this.grade[2]
                + " " + this.grade[3];
    }
}

public class Driver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // here is our main
        try {
            // Menu();
            FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream("input.txt");
            Scanner readfile = new Scanner(input);
            int studentcount = 0;

            while (readfile.hasNextInt()) {
                studentcount++;
                readfile.nextInt();
                readfile.nextLine();

            } // to know students number

            int id;
            String name, FirstName, LastName, line;
            double grade[] = new double[4];
            Scanner ReadScanner = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("input.txt"));
            Student studentarray[] = new Student[studentcount];
            int NumberofStudent = 0;
            while (ReadScanner.hasNextLine()) {
                line = ReadScanner.nextLine();
                id = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(0, line.indexOf(' ')));
                line = line.substring(line.indexOf(' ') + 1);
                FirstName = line.substring(0, line.indexOf(' '));
                line = line.substring(line.indexOf(' ') + 1);
                LastName = line.substring(0, line.indexOf(' '));
                line = line.substring(line.indexOf(' ') + 1);
                name = FirstName + " " + LastName;
                int i = 0;
                // System.out.println(line);
                while (!line.isEmpty()) {

                    grade[i] = Double.parseDouble(line.substring(0, line.indexOf(' ')));
                    line = line.substring(line.indexOf(' ') + 1);
                    i++;
                }

                studentarray[NumberofStudent] = new Student(name, id, grade);
                System.out.println(grade[0]);
                NumberofStudent++;

            }

            for (int k = 0; k < studentarray.length; k++) {
                System.out.println(studentarray[k]);
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found");
        }

    }
}
```

My input.txt :

```
91007 Ahmad Said 50.0 32.0 
91004 Hassan Khan 45.5 
91003 Suleiman Wasim 72.6 52.0 54.2 
91002 Majed Sameer 60.0 
91006 Muhammad Adel 85.5 
91005 Muhsim Zuheir 70.0 
91001 Muneeb Abdullatif 30.0
```

Comment: This code is way too big for us to quickly pinpoint the problem. Did you try debugging it?

Comment: Your `addGrade()` method, **does nothing**.

Comment: Sorry I have edited the code again I hope its simple now..

Comment: why are you override your studentarray inside the loop? Instead, use the setter methods in order to set your variable. In addition, do not use array on students grade and for  the number of students. use list instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the following line is outside the `while` loop:

```
double grade[] = new double[4];
```

Just put it inside the while loop as follows and you will get the result as you are expecting:

```
while (ReadScanner.hasNextLine()) {
    double grade[] = new double[4];
    ...
    ...
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple things you should do is get rid of your `arrays` and make them into lists:

`List<Double> grade` and `List<Student> students`

This would make it easier as you will not have to define how many students you have before hand while reading the file:

Modify your Student constructor to take in the list of grades instead of an array of grades:

```
public Student(String name , int id, List<Double> grades) {
  // here is our constructor
  this.name=name;
  this.studentID=id;
  this.grade = grades;
}
```

Which then can simplify the `toString()` function of `Student` as such:

```
public String toString() {
  String ret = String.format("%6d %-25s %s", studentID, name, grade.stream().map(d -> String.valueOf(d)).collect(Collectors.joining(" ")));
  return ret;
}
```

Also I'd suggest to split the line off space in the (since its space delimited, instead of doing line trimming (unless there is a need for this) and the main method can be simplified as such:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // here is our main 
  try {
    //  Menu();
    List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
    try(Scanner scanner = new Scanner(Files.newInputStream(Paths.get("input.txt")))) {
      while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        String[] stringArgs = line.split(" ");

        int id = Integer.parseInt(stringArgs[0]);
        String firstName = stringArgs[1];
        String lastName = stringArgs [2];
        String name = firstName + " " + lastName;

        List<Double> grades = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 3; i < stringArgs.length; i++) {
          grades.add(Double.parseDouble(stringArgs[i]));
        }

        //Note the below code is if we want to stay with array instead of list for grades
        int gradeLength = stringArgs.length - 3;
        double[] grades = new double[gradeLength]; //need to handle negative length;
        for(int i = 3; i < stringArgs.length; i++) {
          grades[i - 3] = Double.parseDouble(stringArgs[i]);
        }
        //end extra code

        students.add(new Student(name, id, grades));
      }
    }

    for(Student s : students) {
      System.out.println(s);
    }

  } catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
  }
}
```

This will produce the following output:

```
 91007 Ahmad Said                50.0 32.0
 91004 Hassan Khan               45.5
 91003 Suleiman Wasim            72.6 52.0 54.2
 91002 Majed Sameer              60.0
 91006 Muhammad Adel             85.5
 91005 Muhsim Zuheir             70.0
 91001 Muneeb Abdullatif         30.0
```

Comment: i can't use this BufferedReader

Comment: Why can't you used `BufferedReader`?

Comment: See my change, Switched to using `Scanner` instead of `BufferedReader`

Comment: it works thank you but the problem was simple and tricky ... the grade[] have to be inside the loop.

Comment: I address that too. You should do away with predefined array sizes and go with `List<Double>` instead. It will make adding grades easier. Also added logic to keep the array too.